# get woocommerce product image url and price from database

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, sql

I want to get some product data directly from the database, currently I have this, but I'm missing the featured image URL:

```
 SELECT 
  p.ID,
  p.post_title,
  `post_content`,
  `post_excerpt`,
  t.name AS product_category,
  t.term_id AS product_id,
  t.slug AS product_slug,
  tt.term_taxonomy_id AS tt_term_taxonomia,
  tr.term_taxonomy_id AS tr_term_taxonomia,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as price,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sku' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as sku 
FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON pm1.post_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE p.post_type in('product', 'product_variation') AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_content <> ''
GROUP BY p.ID,p.post_title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to use nested `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT p.*, pm2.meta_value as image_file FROM (
  SELECT 
    p.ID,
    p.post_title,
    `post_content`,
    `post_excerpt`,
    t.name AS product_category,
    t.term_id AS product_id,
    t.slug AS product_slug,
    tt.term_taxonomy_id AS tt_term_taxonomia,
    tr.term_taxonomy_id AS tr_term_taxonomia,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sku' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as sku,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as thumbnail_id
  FROM wp_posts p 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON pm1.post_id = p.ID
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = 
  tr.term_taxonomy_id 
  JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
  WHERE p.post_type in('product', 'product_variation') AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_content <> ''
  GROUP BY p.ID,p.post_title
) as p
JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON pm2.post_id = p.thumbnail_id
WHERE pm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
```